# Advanced search in Laravel and MySql

Tags: mysql, laravel, search, eloquent

```
$query = 'Shaikh Shamim Reza'
```

DB columns 'title', 'short_title', 'content', 'reporter'

I want to search the columns with eloquent or in raw query to search

1) Match whole query string (Shaikh Shamim Reza) if matched then return it

if 1 is empty

2) Match first two words (Shaikh Shamim) if matched return it

if fails

if 2 is empty

3) Match last two words (Shamim Reza) if matched return it

Basically I want to first search the full string the any combination of the words but not just a single word need to search in a combination of the words.

Comment: You should look at elasticsearch or algolia if your web app is big

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

So break it down:

```
$split = explode(' ', $query);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE title = :title1 OR title = :title2 OR title = :title3";

$q = $db->prepare($sql);

$q->bind(':title1', $query);
$q->bind(':title2', $split[1] . ' ' . $split[1]);
$q->bind(':title3', $split[1] . ' ' . $split[2]);
```

Comment: If you want a specific order, then I recommend doing 3 queries (If the first one fails, move on to the second or third). As long as your fields like title are indexed, these should be lightning quick, and should not cause an impact at all running 3 in a row.